# Use string paths to images instead of requires when resolving img src and background-image urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I've got image loading working with webpack through file loader, however only if I require or import images. I was wondering how [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) achieves their functionality where everything that is placed in `public` folder is accessible i.e. `<img src="/images/myLogo.jpg" />` works given that `public/images/myLogo.jpg` exists.

My project is structured in the following way

```
src/
  assets/
   images/
   fonts/
  components/
  index.js
  index.html
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

Is it possible to make it so despite where I am in my js files I could use `<img src="/assets/images..."` and `background-image: url(/assets/images/...)` to resolve my to files in my assets folder? Or at least something similar that doesn't require me to import these asset files?

Comment: you can do `eject` to check how webpack inside `create-react-app` is configured.

Comment: I actually found the file in their github repo, but was not able to follow logic fully as I wasn't sure what to look for. Initially I thought it is related to `publicPath`, but reading that cinfig further they seem to be doing more stuff and it is different depending on prod or dev environment

Comment: As it's packaged (inside create-react-app) there must be lot of stuff that must work for everyone out of the box, without ejecting. So it's better to eject and have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliasing in webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
      Images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/images')
    }
  }
};
```

Then in your code you can access like:

```
import myimpage from 'Assets/images/myimage.png'
import another from 'Images/another.png'
```

or for an image:

```
<img src={require('Images/another.png')} />
```

Comment: This still uses require / import pattern as opposed to strings though?